# Solving an integral equation involving powers of a function

Tags: integration

How does one solve for $f$ in this equation

$$\int{{(f(x)})^{\beta -1}dx}=(C_1+C_2x^{a})\int{{(f(x)})^{\beta} \, dx } $$
where $C_1, C_2, a,$ and $\beta$ are constants?

I tried using integration by parts on the left to see if I could get a similar integral to the one on the right so that I could cancel them out but it got really messy. I have no idea what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

differentiating both sides gives:
$$f^{b-1}(x)=(C_1+C_2ax^{a-1})\int f^b(x)dx+(C_1+C_2x^a)f^b(x)$$
now try rearranging to get a differential equations